# placement point of a movieclip in actionscript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I've import a jpeg into my flash library and modify it to movie clip. Now I have a movie clip called as "enemyShip". You can see it here : http://prntscr.com/2porvt

I set the dimensions of it :

```
enemyShip.height=30;
enemyShip.width=40;
```

I want to know that when I write  `enemyShip.x=50;` which point of the movie clip is exactly fitted into 50th pixel. Is there anyone to help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it would be the movieclip's registration point. Or you can think of it as the movieclip's origin. In your screenshot, it would be the little + sign. To line up your graphic, you'd need to go in to it and adjust it as needed.

Comment: thanks for reply,I've also thought like you. But I couldnt understand what you tried to explain with  "To line up your graphic, you'd need to go in to it and adjust it as needed." part ?

Comment: he means you should enter the movieclip in the library (doubleclick) and align it to the little + sign manually, or with the alignment tool

Comment: @MartonPallagi thanks for explanation, one more question, when I rotate the movie clip, + symbol also rotates as a same rate ?

Comment: When you rotate the movieclip (using code), the registration point acts as the pivot.

Comment: @mitim what do you mean by acts as the pivot ?

Comment: the pivot is the point in which everything (inside that movieclip) will rotate around. Just try it and see.